# mvn eclipse:eclipse from parent POM.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

I'm working on a project with many modules. I would like to have a single command to build each module and generate Eclipse configuration files, but when I run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on the parent pom, Eclipse does not see the dependencies and gives me this error: `'module2' is missing required Java project: 'module1'`. When I run the same command in the folder for the module instead of the parent folder it works fine.

The project is set up like this, where module2 depends on module 1.

```
.
 |-- module1
 |   `-- pom.xml
 |-- module2
 |   `-- pom.xml
 `-- pom.xml
```

Here's a comparison of the .project and .classpath for when I run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` in the parent folder vs the module folder:

```
$ diff module_project parent_project
5c5,10
<   <projects/>
---
>   <projects>
>     <project>module1</project>
>   </projects>

$ diff module_classpath parent_classpath
15c15
<   <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/path/to/module1/module1-0.1.jar"/>
---
>   <classpathentry kind="src" path="/module1"/>
```

How do I get this working without running the command on each folder individually?

By the way, here's the version numbers that I am using. Eclipse and maven were both installed using apt-get on Ubuntu 13.10.

```
Eclipse:
Version: 3.8.1
Build id: debbuild

Maven:
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.11.0-15-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the command eclipse:eclipse from the parent folder, you need to open both of your projects 'module1' & 'module2' in the same workspace in order for it to work.

In the first case :

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/path/to/module1/module1-0.1.jar"/>
```

if you want to run your project 'module2' from eclipse it will look for its dependency 'module1' in the repository, that's mean any change you made in 'module1' won't be available for project module2 until you install it in the repository.

In the second case :

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="/module1"/>
```

any change you made to project module1 will be immediately available for project module2, because the two projects are linked directly in the same workspace.

Comment: Yes! The answer seems to be that the project somehow detected that module1 was in the same project and tried to read it from eclipse, while the foldername "module1" wasn't found because the folder was named "Module1".

Comment: Rida, if you don't mind, do you know how to switch the behavior of mvn eclipse:eclipse so that running the command in the module will behave like running the command in the parent folder or vice versa?